# An uncaught Exception was encountered in hmvc

Tags: codeigniter

An uncaught Exception was encountered

> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method MY_Loader::_ci_object_to_array()
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\hhh\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 300

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how to reproduce the exception. It's currently hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: A simple google search would have helped you figure this out in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add it in the MY_Loader.

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* load the MX_Loader class */
require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Loader.php";

class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader
{
    /** Load a module view **/
    public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        list($path, $_view) = Modules::find($view, $this->_module, 'views/');

        if ($path != FALSE)
        {
            $this->_ci_view_paths = array($path => TRUE) + $this->_ci_view_paths;
            $view = $_view;
        }

        return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => ((method_exists($this,'_ci_object_to_array')) ? $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars) : $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars)), '_ci_return' => $return));
    }
}
```